# Disable button dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios6, cordova

I am using JqueryMobile-1.3.0 and cordova-2.1.0 for iOS app.I want to disable the button on pageshow event.I am doing like this `$('#clearButton').attr('disabled', "")` and button is
 `<input type='button' data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="clearButton" value="Clear" onclick='resetLogin();'/>`

Its disabling the buttons onclick event but the style of button remains as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [disable()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-disable) method of the button widget:

```
$("#clearButton").button("disable");
```

That way, the element will be disabled and the widget will properly reflect that state. You can call its [enable()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#method-enable) method later to re-enable the button.